# insert into database unknown error

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I am trying to do a simple insert into database but cannot find where the problem is. If anyone could help would be great please. My code:

```
if(isset($_POST['s1']))
{
    $q1 = "INSERT INTO tienda (title,desc) VALUES ('$title', '$desc')";

                mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<div class=alert fade in><b>Group added!</b></div>";
}
```

The field side of things:

```
<tr>
    <b>Titulo</b>
      <input type=text name=title value="<?=$aset['title']?>" size=50> <br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <b>Descripcion</b>
      <input type=text name=desc value="<?=$aset['desc']?>" size=50> <br>
    </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td> 
        <input type=submit name=s1 value=Upload class="btn btn-primary">
```

The error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc)
VALUES (' Title ', '1')' at line 1
```

Comment: [mysql_query is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), consider using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or the more generic [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.  The code you have written is vulnerable to a [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), look into [bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for how to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`desc` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL (short for description, used in the order by statement). Try enclosing that in backticks like

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO tienda (title,`desc`) VALUES ('$title', '$desc')";
```

Comment: Yes, it is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Thanks @jpw You are rigth. I will mark as answer correct. Thanks again!